# load application.ini

Tags: zend-framework

We use:
- Zend_Controller_Front
- no Zend_Application
- no Zend_Application_Bootstrap

We want to use application.ini.

```
require_once("Zend/Controller/Front.php");

class Forum4Php_Bootstrap {

    protected $_dispatcher;

    public function  __construct() {
        $this->_dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    }

    public function runApp() {
        $this->_dispatcher->addModuleDirectory(FORUM_FOR_PHP_ROOT_DIR."/application/modules");
        $this->_dispatcher->dispatch();
    }
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `parse_ini_file` as karim79 suggested or pass the path to your .ini file to a [`Zend_Config_Ini`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) object:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/application.ini', 'development');
```

Comment: If I have db connection config in application.ini, will it make database connection?

Comment: Not if you're not using Zend_Application and the Db module. Seems like you are creating a custom bootstrap, so you'll have to create a Db Adapter manually.